# Unknown characters preceding XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a VB.Net app we use to report problems from the field.

It generates a XML file. That file along with others are emailed to our problem report mail server.

Every once in a while the XML file is proceeded by some characters that I have no idea where they come from. Example:

```
o;?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProblemReport>
  <Project Name="AccuMark">
    <Record>
      <FieldString Name="Title">CUT SEQUENCE</FieldString>
```

The `o;?` are not supposed to be there, this particular email was generated in Austria. The hex codes are 6F 3B 3F. I've never seen more that 3 unknown characters, sometimes just 1. The code looks like this:

```
Dim XML As XmlTextWriter
XML = New XmlTextWriter(strFilePathName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    XML.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

    XML.WriteStartDocument(True)    'Standalone = True
    XML.WriteStartElement("ProblemReport")
    XML.WriteStartElement("Project")
    XML.WriteAttributeString("Name", cboProduct)

    XML.WriteStartElement("Record")

    XML.WriteStartElement("FieldString")
```

Since it's in the XML file itself I'm thinking the writer is putting this in there for some reason.

Comment: Is the filepath you're writing to a different one each time? Not something that you've been overwriting each time with left over data?

Comment: did you also write `XML.WriteEndElement() XML.WriteEndDocument()` and `XML.Close()` to close the elements and document ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in C# once. The problem was in UTF-8 encoding with BOM. You can instruct `XmlTextWriter` to write in UTF-8 with or without BOM. When BOM is used, some interpreters show the first 3 bytes as invalid characters. Take a look at [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b8d1603-3e76-4b09-b9a8-e529d93f9e0a/how-to-suppress-the-bom-while-using-xmltextwriter?forum=xmlandnetfx) and [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/465393-invalid-characters-before-xml-header) . But the BOM bytes in UTF-8 are "EF BB BF". Interesting is that EF-80=6F, BB-80=3B, BF-80=3F.

Comment: I will look at these, thanks. The file is always new, if it exist I delete it and yes I'm calling WriteEndElement() and WriteendDocument().

Comment: I ended up forcing the XML writer to NOT append the BOM doing the following: I still need to test on a number of none US systems (non English)

strFilePathName = g_strTempDir & g_strProblemID & "-XML.TXT"
        Call DeleteFile(strFilePathName)

        Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
        settings.Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(False) ' The false means, do not emit the BOM.

        XML = New XmlTextWriter(strFilePathName, settings.Encoding)